# Out of Memory error/crash after using scroll throughout a tableView of custom rows containing views in titanium appcelerator for android

Tags: android, scroll, tableview, appcelerator

I am using titanium appcelerator for android to write my app.

On my main screen i have a tableView, full of listings that are rows, that paginates 15 at a time. So once u scroll down to 15th row another 15 rows will be added to the table. A screen usually shows 3 to 10 of the rows at a time depending on screen height (samsung mini vs nexus 7)

Each row contains a view which contains several child Views and imageViews. This cause very slow performance when scrolling up and down the list. To solve this i turned the parent view which is added to the row into an image, which increased performance massively when scrolling.

Here is a general snippet

```js
    //Turn the entire view "post_view" into an image. post_view consists of many child views    
    var blob = post_view.toImage(null, true);

    //Create the Image view of entire post_view, the parent of all child views
    var tempImage = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    height : 'auto',
    width : 'auto',
    top : 0,
    zindex : 3,
    image : blob
    });         


    /* adding the ImageView created from the parent view which all child ies have      been added to*/
   row.add(tempImage);

    /*This is the array of rows to be added to the tableView */
    tabData[i] = row;


    ........

    tableView.appendRow(tabData);
```

However, especially on larger screens when u scroll the app crashes, which using DDMS shows as OutOfMemory error. Which unfortunately i cant post the specific error right now because i dont have access to a larger device now. Also the memory error does also occur when i dont use the method of changing the entire view to an image, but gives less detail on the errors themselves in DDMS.

So im not sure if its related to the toImage method, or im not freeing memory properly in javascript, or if its a titanium or java issue or what.

Anyone any ideas. This has been a problem im trying to fix for a few weeks. I wish i had the specific java errors on hand. But they mostly refer to OutOfMemory

Comment: how large are the images?

Comment: Hi, they are 82 dp high, but their width is defendant on the screen Width. So a small device the images may be only 82*320 dp, with only 3 visible at a time (where i cant seem to run out of memory and the app works fine). But on a nexus 7 it may be 82*720 with 8-10 visible at one time and out of memory crash can happen after a mere few scrolls down the page.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Thanks